# Nginx "set_real_ip_from" use value from a local variable

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to set the value of `set_real_ip_from` from a variable but I'm getting an error.

NGINX Config:

```
set $frontendIP "104.22.100.4/32";

set_real_ip_from 103.21.244.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.22.200.0/22;

set_real_ip_from $frontendIP;
```

---

Error:

```
nginx: [emerg] host not found in set_real_ip_from "$frontendIP"
```

The problem is not in setting the variable, but set_real_ip_from returning an error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nginx set variable in location](https://serverfault.com/questions/644892/nginx-set-variable-in-location)

Comment: Also see http://nginx.org/en/docs/faq/variables_in_config.html

Comment: @AlexD, the problem isn't in setting the variable but set_real_ip_from isn't taking the variable and returning an error.